# Односоставность личных предложений

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Определенно-личные, неопределенно-личные предложения считаются в школе односоставными. В то же время признается, что назывные предложения, если в них есть обстоятельства места или времени, могут быть трактованы как двусоставные неполные с нулевым глаголом, ср. *Скоро осень* и *Скоро наступит осень*.

Так почему же не говорят о нулевых подлежащих в предложениях типа *Иду. В дверь стучат.* и считают их лишь односоставными?

Answer (score 2):

В школе - да, именно так: определённо-личные, неопределённо-личные, обобщённо-личные считаются односоставными, потому что субъект (вполне определённое лицо в опр.-личных и неопределённое лицо в неопр.-личных) выражен семантически и грамматически формой личного глагола, его окончанием, состав подлежащего здесь не нужен для понимания субъекта-деятеля.

Номинативное тоже односоставное, только с подлежащим в роли главного члена, потому что здесь не нужен состав сказуемого, номинативные предложения выражают значения **бытия**, **наличия**  предмета (иногда указания на него или эмоции) в настоящем времени, совпадающем о временем информации о его бытии. Если же есть обстоятельство или дополнение, то это уже состав сказуемого, ведь обстоятельство к подлежащему относиться не может. Значит, здесь есть сказуемое, материально не выраженное.

Но это в школе, чтобы не запутывать учеников, а в лингвистической науке в современных синтаксических исследованиях вопрос о выделении односоставной определенно-личной конструкции в качестве самостоятельной синтаксической категории не решен.Следующие исследователи выделяют среди односоставных предложений определенно-личные: Т.Г. Почтенная, А.А. Юдин, Е.А. Седельников, А.Г. Руднев, В.В. Бабайцева и др.  **Ряд  же ученых относят односоставные конструкции к двусоставным неполным предложениям, некоторые ученые считают все двусоставные конструкции определенно-личными предложениями.**

Важным для решения вопроса о выделении любого типа предложения является определение его формально-грамматических признаков и семантической функции, учитывающие как план содержания, так и план выражения.

Точно так же обстоит дело и с номинативными. Назывные предложения не могут быть употреблены ни в прошедшем, ни в будущем времени, ни в сослагательном, ни в повелительном наклонении. В этих временах и наклонениях им соответствуют двусоставные личные предложения со сказуемым было или будет: *Зима* (назывное предложение). *Была зима. Будет зима* (двусоставные личные предложения).

Из второстепенных членов предложения в назывных предложениях бывают только согласованные и несогласованные определения: *Унылая пора! Очей очарованье! (А.С. Пушкин)*

Если второстепенный член — обстоятельство или дополнение (В доме праздник; У меня хандра), некоторые ученые считают предложение двусоставным с пропущенным сказуемым на том основании, что к подлежащему не может относиться ни обстоятельство, ни дополнение. Другие ученые считают такие предложения назывными, с особым второстепенным членом, который относится ко всему предложению, распространяя его в целом, и называется детерминантом.

Как отличать назывные предложения от двусоставных?
•   Предложение *Какая погода!* назывное, где слово какая — частица. Предложение Какая погода?  двусоставное, где вопросительное местоимение какая — составное именное сказуемое с нулевой связкой.

•   Важно отличать назывные предложения с частицей вот от двусоставных с местоимением это: *Вот стул* — односоставное назывное предложение; *Это стул* — двусоставное, где это — подлежащее, а стул — составное именное сказуемое с нулевой связкой.

•   Порядок слов в предложении может влиять на его состав. Так, в предложении *Теплый день* легко обнаруживаются подлежащее и определение, выраженное именем прилагательным, стоящим перед определяемым словом. Это — односоставное назывное распространенное предложение. В предложении же *День теплый* есть подлежащее и составное именное сказуемое с нулевой связкой и именной частью, выраженной именем прилагательным, стоящим после подлежащего. Это — двусоставное нераспространенное предложение.

•    Предложение *Было скучно его слушать* считается односоставным безличным с составным глагольным сказуемым, где вместо вспомогательного глагола — слово категории состояния скучно и глагол-связка было. Но если инфинитив поставить на первое место — *Слушать его было скучно*, его можно рассматривать как подлежащее, тогда было скучно — составное именное сказуемое, где именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным (ср. *Слушанье было скучно*).

https://studfiles.net/preview/4677269/page:14/

https://helpiks.org/9-27649.html

Answer (score 1):

***Скоро осень*** — это не назывное, а эллиптическое двусоставное предложение, составленное по схеме "обстоятельство — подлежащее".

***Осень.*** Это назывное предложение.

1) Любое предложение, в отличие от словосочетания, сообщает о том, что с предметом (подлежащее) что-то происходит (сказуемое). **Основное свойство предложения — это предикативность,** при этом предмет соотносится с действительностью и ему приписывается **модальность и время.**

Эти **семантические характеристики** присутствуют в каждом предложении, односоставном или двусоставном.

2) **Состав — это структурная характеристика предложения.** В односоставном предложении обычно нет подлежащего, но  субъект действия всегда присутствует, просто он не назван. Его можно восстановить по форме глагола (***иду***), он может быть выражен падежной формой в безличном предложении (***мне холодно***), он неизвестен или неважен, но по смыслу он всегда есть.

3) **Назывные (номинативные) предложения** — особый вид односоставных предложений. Действие в них не названо, но значение предикативности (реальной модальности и настоящего времени)  тоже есть.

**Они бывают разного вида:** собственно-бытийные (Земская больница.) выражают значение **существования** предмета, номинативно-бытийные (**Картины на стене.**)предполагают наличие предмета в поле зрения наблюдателя, событийные предложения обозначают отрезки времени, явления природы (**Ночь. Зима. Утро.**)

Назывные односоставные предложения **легко переходят** в двусоставные: ***Картина на стене. На стене — картина*** (изображается пространство).

Это говорит о том, что сходную семантику можно представить предложениями разной структуры: **Иду. — Я иду. Стучат! — Кто-то стучит. Ваза на столе. — На столе — ваза.**